# How to detect if a library is using the XP compatibility (v120_xp)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp

I have a big native C++ project which is build by many specific and 3rd party libraries in Visual Studio 2013.
I am compiling for both 64 bits and 32 bits architecture.
For the 32 bits architecture I set (for both the 3rd party and our libraries) the XP toolset (v120_xp) to keep the compatibility with Windows XP.

Recently we have updated a library and from the error we receive it looks like some of the library has not been set properly for XP. Is it possible with Dependancy Walker or other tools to detect which is the toolset used to build the DLL or the EXE?
I just need any way to check which library is not XP compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dumpbin /headers my_program.exe` and look for the operating system version and subsystem version.  When building for Windows XP they will be 5.01.  When not building for Windows XP they will be 6.00.

(This isn't foolproof--if the DLL or EXE declares that it runs on Windows XP but tries to use Windows APIs that are not available on Windows XP, then obviously the DLL or EXE won't run on Windows XP.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but actually also when it's written 6.00 works on Windows XP, but I discovered that SP3 was needed.